# Como imprimir caracteres especiais pelo CMD ao formatar moedas?

Tags: java

Há alguns dia atrás fiz um exercício para formatar moedas e usei o seguinte código para isso:

```
String us, china, france;
us = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).format(payment);
china = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CHINA).format(payment);
france = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE).format(payment);
```

No prompt de comando deveria sair algo assim:

```
US: $12,324.13
China: ￥12,324.13
France: 12 324,13 €
```

Mas saiu algo assim:

```
US: $12,324.13
China: ?12,324.13
France: 12▒324,13 ▒
```

Sei que o código está correto, pois funcionou, mas ele não é exibido da forma correta. Como faço para que sempre que eu precisar rodar caracteres especiais pelo CMD eles sejam exibidos corretamente?

Comment: Creio que este problema não seja de java, e sim da codificação aceita pelo prompt

Comment: Entendo, mas existe algo que possa ser feito para arrumar isso, @Articuno?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O mais confiável seria usar a GUI. Exemplo mínimo:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new String[] {us, china, france});
```

No `CMD` não vai conseguir mostrar todos os símbolos corretamente pois basicamente não tem suporte para Unicode. Com

```
> CHCP 1252
```

vai conseguir mostrar o `€` (Euro) mas provavelmente não o `￥` (\uFFE5, Yen).
Talvez essa página sobre [CHCP](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) ajude mais...

No Stackoverflow Inglês tem essa [questão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using) com algumas respostas que podem ajudar.

Comment: Testei sua sugestão de usar o JOptionPane e deu certo também. Vou usar isso, quando precisar executar pelo cmd/terminal! Muito obrigada! ^_^